# Kiosk mode for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 22.04, desktop-environments, kiosk

I need to create a user session that starts only an application without the operating system facilities. My target PC is Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.

I done a lot of searches on the web, starting with the Ubuntu official documentations, but they do not cover my needs (they discuss about Web Kiosk, Ubuntu Core, ...). I found a guide on GNOME forum (here the link: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-single-app-mode.html.en) that seems the closest to my needs, but it does not work: nothing is happening when I reboot.

When I was starting to ask me how to do kiosk, I thought it was not very difficult to do that, maybe I am missing some steps.
Could anyone give me some suggestions?
Thank you so much,
Gianluca

Comment: Have you considered a simple `startx` with the application you need?